# First modalpopup in first panel does not open until second modalpopup opens in second panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have one updatepanel exists with two panels. Each panel have two buttons to open popup. I have two modalpopup & its target panels just below of two panels.Everything is working fine, but I am getting problem, if I click button in first panel then modalpopup does not open, but when I click button in second panel after click button in first panel then popup opens & viceversa.
I used following code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" class="add-btn-1" Text="Add" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" class="add-btn-1" Text="Add" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopup1" PopupControlID="pnlpopup1" TargetControlID="btn1"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlpopup1">
    <%--code here--%>
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopup2" PopupControlID="pnlpopup2" TargetControlID="btn2"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlpopup2">
    <%--code here--%>
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

What will be solution to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code and found no problems.It works.So post the code that you have given inside **<%--code here--%>**.I would also suggest that you add a **OkControlID** to your ModalPopupExtender.

Comment: code works perfect but modalpopup opens on second click of button not on first click of button

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" class="add-btn-1" Text="Add" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" class="add-btn-1" Text="Add" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <Ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopup1" PopupControlID="pnlpopup1" TargetControlID="btn1"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlpopup1" Style="width:400px;height:100px; background: gray;">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblheadinglunchout" Font-Underline="true" Text="First Popup"
                            runat="server" CssClass="labelPopup" Style="text-decoration: none"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:ImageButton  ID="imgbtnCancelPopUp" ImageUrl="Images/popupclose_button.png"
                            runat="server" Style="vertical-align: top;" CssClass="button" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        <Ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopup2" PopupControlID="pnlpopup2" TargetControlID="btn2"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlpopup2" Style="width:400px;height:100px; background: gray;">
           <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Underline="true" Text="Secound Popup"
                            runat="server" CssClass="labelPopup" Style="text-decoration: none"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="Images/popupclose_button.png"
                            runat="server" Style="vertical-align: top;" CssClass="button" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```